# Getting started with purescript

Tags: functional-programming, ffi, purescript

I just started learning purescript following [purescript by example](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read) but I am stuck at the end of [Chapter2 using grunt project templates](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read#leanpub-auto-using-grunt-project-templates).
I follow the instructions, but when I run the grunt command I get this error:

```
/Users/chad/playground/purescript/tests/tmp/node_modules/Control.Monad.Eff.Random/index.js:8
return Math.random();
            ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.random (/Users/chad/playground/purescript/tests/tmp/node_modules/Control.Monad.Eff.Random/index.js:8:17)
    at __do (/Users/chad/playground/purescript/tests/tmp/node_modules/Test.QuickCheck/index.js:177:52)
    at Object.__do (/Users/chad/playground/purescript/tests/tmp/node_modules/Main/index.js:19:201)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/chad/playground/purescript/tests/tmp/index.js:1:79)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
Warning: -> error 1 /Users/chad/playground/purescript/tests/tmp/index.js (125ms) Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

What I discovered by digging into the code is that the module Math gets imported into `/output/Control.Monad.Eff.Random/index.js` as

```
var Math = require("Math");

function random() {
    return Math.random();
}
;
```

If I remove the import, letting Math being native and running the main `index.js` simply with `node index.js`, everything works fine.
I was wondering if there is something I can do to fix this in purescript, or if it is something I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why's this tagged [tag:haskell]? It's true that PureScript is related to Haskell, and that the PureScript compiler is written in Haskell, but they are not the same language.

Comment: I removed the haskell tag now, I initially added it because a number of other purescript questions are using that combination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `purescript-random` module is broken in the latest release when used with `psc-make`. It will be fixed by a compiler patch in the next release, 0.6.7, hopefully this week.

As a workaround, you should be able to specify the previous version of `purescript-random` in your `bower.json` file, or on the command line:

```
bower install purescript-random#0.1.1
```

Comment: That's awesome Phil, thank you very much :) Looking forward to start using PureScript in production code soon